# Adding block to product.info on <catalog_product_view> in local.xml

Tags: layout

In `local.xml`, the following block exists. This **does not** insert the block into the `product.info` block (IE `getChild('addtolinks')` returns `false`). Inserting the **same** snippet in `catalog.xml` works just as expected. I don't believe the issue is with the handle (`catalog_product_view`) or reference (`name="product.info"`) because `<remove name="something.in.product.info" />` in the same scope as the block works just fine. Any ideas?

```
<layout>
  <!-- etc... -->
  <catalog_product_view>


    <reference name="product.info">

      <block type="my_catalog/addto_links" name="product.info.addtolinks" as="addtolinks" template="page/template/links.phtml">

        <action method="setProduct">
          <product helper="catalog/getProduct" />
        </action>

        <action method="addLink">
          <label>Add to Wishlist</label>
          <helper>wishlist</helper>
          <title>Add to Wishlist</title>
        </action>

        <action method="addLink">
          <label>Add to Compare</label>
          <helper>catalog/product_compare</helper>
          <title>Add to Compare</title>
        </action>

      </block>

    </reference>
  </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Thanks for reading!

**Update**: Just tested adding a `core/text` block in the same `reference` with expected success:

```
  <block type="core/text" name="testy">
    <action method="setText"><text>hi</text></action>
  </block>
```

**Update 2**: Even more intriguing, the block works in `local.xml` if I change the `type` to `page/template_links` (the parent class of `my_catalog/addto_links`), the block comes into being! Of course, the links are all wrong, because `addLink` has special powers in my block class. Normally, I'd say that the `my_catalog/addto_links` piece was wrong, but it works in `catalog.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to change the function name being called from `addLink` to something else. *Even though* overriding `addLink` works fine in `catalog.xml`, it does not work in `local.xml`. Can anyone offer insight as to why that's the case?